# Неизвестная ошибка PHP или Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Доброе утро, я уже ровно неделю не могу исправить такую проблему: я администрирую браузерную онлайн игру [Травиан](http://www.travianx5.ru). Все было, почти, отлично. Но примерно неделю назад начались серьезные проблемы. Проблема заключается в том, что при отправке войск в атаку они должны пройти какое-либо расстояние, это занимает время. Так вот когда таймер доходит до нуля самого сражения не происходит, а на главной странице деревни такое ощущение, что зажата кнопка F5 (идет вечное обновление страницы)...

[image: Вид деревни в игре Травиан]

Когда сервер не успевает отвечать на запросы, то игрок видит просто пустой экран:

[image: Пустой экран или белый экран]

Вот метод, который отвечают за войска... Я уверен, что проблема именно в нем:
(есть еще два метода, но их выложу как уточнение вопроса)

```
private function sendTroopsBack($post) {
        global $form, $database, $village, $generator, $session, $technology;

        $enforce=$database->getEnforceArray($post['ckey'],0);
            $to = $database->getVillage($enforce['from']);
            $Gtribe = "";
            if ($database->getUserField($to['owner'],'tribe',0) == '2'){ $Gtribe = "1"; } else if ($database->getUserField($to['owner'],'tribe',0) == '3'){ $Gtribe = "2"; } else if ($database->getUserField($to['owner'],'tribe',0) == '4'){ $Gtribe = "3"; }else if ($database->getUserField($to['owner'],'tribe',0) == '5'){ $Gtribe = "4"; }

                    for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){
                        if(isset($post['t'.$i])){
                            if($i!=10){
                                if ($post['t'.$i] > $enforce['u'.$Gtribe.$i])
                                {
                                    $form->addError("error","Вы не можете отправить больше войск чем у Вас есть в наличии");
                                    break;
                                }

                                if($post['t'.$i]<0)
                                {
                                    $form->addError("error","You can't send negative units.");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                        $post['t'.$i.'']='0';
                        }
                    }
                        if(isset($post['t11'])){
                                if ($post['t11'] > $enforce['hero'])
                                {
                                    $form->addError("error","Вы не можете отправить больше войск чем у Вас есть в наличии");
                                    break;
                                }

                                if($post['t11']<0)
                                {
                                    $form->addError("error","You can't send negative units.");
                                    break;
                                }
                        } else {
                        $post['t11']='0';
                        }

                if($form->returnErrors() > 0) {
                    $_SESSION['errorarray'] = $form->getErrors();
                    $_SESSION['valuearray'] = $_POST;
                    header("Location: a2b.php");
                } else {

                    //change units
                    $start = ($database->getUserField($to['owner'],'tribe',0)-1)*10+1;
                    $end = ($database->getUserField($to['owner'],'tribe',0)*10);

                    $j='1';
                    for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i++){
                        $database->modifyEnforce($post['ckey'],$i,$post['t'.$j.''],0); $j++;
                    }

                        //get cord
                        $from = $database->getVillage($enforce['from']);
                        $fromcoor = $database->getCoor($enforce['from']);
                        $tocoor = $database->getCoor($enforce['vref']);
                        $fromCor = array('x'=>$tocoor['x'], 'y'=>$tocoor['y']);
                        $toCor = array('x'=>$fromcoor['x'], 'y'=>$fromcoor['y']);

                $speeds = array();

                //find slowest unit.
                for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
                    if (isset($post['t'.$i])){
                        if( $post['t'.$i] != '' && $post['t'.$i] > 0){
                        if($unitarray) { reset($unitarray); }
                        $unitarray = $GLOBALS["u".(($session->tribe-1)*10+$i)];
                        $speeds[] = $unitarray['speed'];
                    } else {
                        $post['t'.$i.'']='0';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $post['t'.$i.'']='0';
                    }
                }
                    if (isset($post['t11'])){
                        if( $post['t11'] != '' && $post['t11'] > 0){
                        $qh = "SELECT * FROM tx5_hero WHERE uid = ".$from['owner']."";
                        $resulth = mysqli_query($database->connection, $qh);
                        $hero_f=mysqli_fetch_array($resulth);
                        $hero_unit=$hero_f['unit'];
                        $speeds[] = $GLOBALS['u'.$hero_unit]['speed'];
                    } else {
                        $post['t11']='0';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $post['t11']='0';
                    }
            $artefact = count($database->getOwnUniqueArtefactInfo2($from['owner'],2,3,0));
            $artefact1 = count($database->getOwnUniqueArtefactInfo2($from['vref'],2,1,1));
            $artefact2 = count($database->getOwnUniqueArtefactInfo2($from['owner'],2,2,0));
            if($artefact > 0){
            $fastertroops = 3;
            }else if($artefact1 > 0){
            $fastertroops = 2;
            }else if($artefact2 > 0){
            $fastertroops = 1.5;
            }else{
            $fastertroops = 1;
            }
                $time = round($generator->procDistanceTime($fromCor,$toCor,min($speeds),1)/$fastertroops);
                $foolartefact4 = $database->getFoolArtefactInfo(2,$from['wref'],$from['owner']);
                if(count($foolartefact4) > 0){
                foreach($foolartefact4 as $arte){
                if($arte['bad_effect'] == 1){
                $time *= $arte['effect2'];
                }else{
                $time /= $arte['effect2'];
                $time = round($endtime);
                }
                }
                }
                $reference = $database->addAttack($enforce['from'],$post['t1'],$post['t2'],$post['t3'],$post['t4'],$post['t5'],$post['t6'],$post['t7'],$post['t8'],$post['t9'],$post['t10'],$post['t11'],2,0,0,0,0);
                $database->addMovement(4,$village->wid,$enforce['from'],$reference,$AttackArrivalTime,($time+$AttackArrivalTime));
                $technology->checkReinf($post['ckey']);

                        header("Location: build.php?id=39");

                }
    }
```

Вот содержимое файла error.log:

[Sun Jan 26 07:44:00.664877 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1243] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 26 07:44:00.665687 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1243] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jan 26 08:47:43.932856 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 157.55.33.26:44588] script '/var/www/impressum.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:22.921668 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.641323 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.712521 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 744
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.712568 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 822
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.712607 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 674
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.712806 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 744
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.713026 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2481
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.713057 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2457
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.713171 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 3080
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.713202 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 3080
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.713243 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 822
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.713773 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 744
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.713804 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 822
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.713834 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 674
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.713999 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 744
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.714118 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2481
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.714147 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2457
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.714259 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Building.php on line 32
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717756 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Building.php on line 190
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717798 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Building.php on line 190
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717804 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717809 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717814 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717818 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717822 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717825 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717829 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717833 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717837 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717841 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717845 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717849 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717853 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717857 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717860 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717864 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717868 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717872 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717876 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717880 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.717888 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Building.php on line 199
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.772504 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:52405] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 822
[Sun Jan 26 10:41:26.804713 2014] [:error] [pid 19927] [client 192.168.1.1:52406] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269
[Sun Jan 26 10:44:55.592704 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 213.109.5.171:53319] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.069343 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.108292 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 744
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.108327 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 822
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.108353 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 674
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.108503 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 744
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.108608 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2481
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.108630 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2457
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.108772 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 3080
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.108869 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 3080
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.108911 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 822
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.109479 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 744
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.109511 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 822
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.109542 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 674
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.109732 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 744
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.109882 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2481
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.109917 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2457
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110039 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Building.php on line 32
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110108 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Building.php on line 190
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110153 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Building.php on line 190
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110160 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110165 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110170 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110174 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110178 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110182 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110186 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110190 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110194 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110197 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110202 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110206 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110210 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110214 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110218 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110221 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110225 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110229 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110237 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110241 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/Templates/dorf2.tpl on line 73
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110245 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Building.php on line 199
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.110380 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53329] PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 822
[Sun Jan 26 10:45:16.713573 2014] [:error] [pid 20183] [client 213.109.5.171:53330] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269
[Sun Jan 26 10:46:57.076108 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 213.109.5.171:53343] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:01.340955 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 213.109.5.171:53343] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:01.392777 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 213.109.5.171:53343] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'CSRF attack' in /var/www/login.php:26\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/login.php on line 26, referer: www.travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:01.463311 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 213.109.5.171:53343] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:04.123423 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 213.109.5.171:53349] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:04.887442 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 213.109.5.171:53351] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:06.900905 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 213.109.5.171:53355] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:07.523096 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53356] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:09.858389 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 213.109.5.171:53361] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:10.492344 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53356] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:11.494653 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53356] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:12.292077 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 213.109.5.171:53357] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:12.489138 2014] [:error] [pid 20183] [client 213.109.5.171:53359] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:18.962281 2014] [:error] [pid 19926] [client 213.109.5.171:53363] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:37.165948 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 213.109.5.171:53367] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:41.710859 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 213.109.5.171:53367] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/build.php?id=29
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:41.863760 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 213.109.5.171:53368] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/build.php?id=29
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:45.663360 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 213.109.5.171:53368] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:51.697588 2014] [:error] [pid 20183] [client 213.109.5.171:53376] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:47:55.132192 2014] [:error] [pid 20183] [client 213.109.5.171:53376] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:48:07.843505 2014] [:error] [pid 19926] [client 213.109.5.171:53380] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/build.php?id=3
[Sun Jan 26 10:48:08.639249 2014] [:error] [pid 20192] [client 213.109.5.171:53381] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/build.php?id=3
[Sun Jan 26 10:48:15.726311 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53382] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php?a=3&c=dq7
[Sun Jan 26 10:48:15.879953 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 213.109.5.171:53382] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php?a=3&c=dq7
[Sun Jan 26 10:48:27.183704 2014] [:error] [pid 19923] [client 213.109.5.171:53386] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:49:02.104263 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 213.109.5.171:53388] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:49:03.860208 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 213.109.5.171:53388] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:49:30.769990 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 213.109.5.171:53389] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf1.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:50:08.509198 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 213.109.5.171:53393] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:50:40.792757 2014] [:error] [pid 20183] [client 213.109.5.171:53396] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:51:09.515039 2014] [:error] [pid 19923] [client 213.109.5.171:53399] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:51:12.505421 2014] [:error] [pid 19923] [client 213.109.5.171:53399] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:52:11.432871 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 95.179.9.58:53404] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:52:57.003883 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 95.179.9.58:53408] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:41.531259 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60110] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:43.840555 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60110] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:51.649599 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60147] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:51.676013 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60147] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'CSRF attack' in /var/www/login.php:26\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/login.php on line 26, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:51.784120 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60147] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:52.310737 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60152] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:52.925136 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60150] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:53.109953 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60148] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:53.314324 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60148] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:53.494920 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60150] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:53.689131 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60150] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:53.894029 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60150] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:54.023730 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60148] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:54.177660 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60147] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:54.313549 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60147] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:54.449368 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60147] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:54.576356 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60150] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:54.704225 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60161] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:54.854141 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60152] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:55.028047 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60147] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:55.221274 2014] [:error] [pid 20229] [client 192.168.1.1:60149] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:55.398898 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60152] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:55.520937 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60148] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:55.648647 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60152] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:55.777733 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60161] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:55.935203 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 192.168.1.1:60169] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:56.069719 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60161] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:56.218199 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60161] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:56.350069 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60161] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:56.474115 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60161] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:56.607946 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60161] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:56.778139 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 192.168.1.1:60169] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:56.976961 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60170] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:57.159559 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60166] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:57.395085 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60171] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:57.603366 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60170] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:57.743911 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60174] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:57.871935 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60171] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:58.049175 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60170] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:58.240356 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 192.168.1.1:60169] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:58.406936 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60171] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:58.557743 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60171] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:58.702010 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60174] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:58.855841 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60174] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:59.002098 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60178] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:59.200326 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60178] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:59.352828 2014] [:error] [pid 20229] [client 192.168.1.1:60183] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:59.538277 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60178] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:59.697550 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60178] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:56:59.845335 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60187] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:00.018670 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60193] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:00.223679 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60184] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:00.407365 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60184] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:00.567893 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60187] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:00.732741 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60184] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:00.891048 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60188] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:01.017977 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60194] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:01.172289 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60187] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:01.308108 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60193] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:01.433964 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60199] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:01.562410 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60188] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:01.693190 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60193] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:01.855287 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60193] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:02.038707 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60199] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:02.252910 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60199] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:02.435415 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60205] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:02.618964 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60194] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:02.744632 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60205] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:02.874057 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60205] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:03.043644 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60205] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:03.232748 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60199] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:03.391258 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60205] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:03.592498 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 192.168.1.1:60202] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:03.899151 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60206] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:04.371496 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60209] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:04.963356 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60209] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:05.141706 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60209] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:05.348392 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60212] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:05.530079 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60212] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:05.697232 2014] [:error] [pid 20229] [client 192.168.1.1:60217] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:06.365802 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60209] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:06.561070 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60209] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:06.723931 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60212] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:06.902315 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60212] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:07.107653 2014] [:error] [pid 20229] [client 192.168.1.1:60217] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:07.307413 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60225] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:07.499895 2014] [:error] [pid 20229] [client 192.168.1.1:60217] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:07.676537 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60225] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:07.839289 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60225] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:08.041458 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 192.168.1.1:60231] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:08.204309 2014] [:error] [pid 20229] [client 192.168.1.1:60217] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:08.338530 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60230] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:08.469158 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60222] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:08.602287 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60222] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:08.723112 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60222] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:08.871629 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60239] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:09.002585 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60236] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:09.157089 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60230] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:09.293720 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60230] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:09.427860 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60230] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:09.559693 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60230] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:09.691908 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60230] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:09.843279 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60230] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:10.034219 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60236] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:10.240343 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60239] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:10.470433 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60236] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:10.684750 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60236] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:10.958929 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60236] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:11.092476 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60239] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:11.248806 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60243] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:11.392613 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60240] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:11.521140 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60239] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:11.652744 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60239] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:11.790188 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60243] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:12.102698 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60246] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:12.321863 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60243] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:12.488933 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60243] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:12.901624 2014] [:error] [pid 20229] [client 192.168.1.1:60249] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:13.032577 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60254] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:13.203073 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60254] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:13.354416 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60254] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:13.487945 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 192.168.1.1:60254] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:13.627719 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60258] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:13.769408 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60257] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:14.014010 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60257] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:14.179712 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60258] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:14.346440 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60258] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:14.489404 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60257] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:14.635546 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60262] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:14.769377 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60258] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:14.954154 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60262] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:15.159702 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60271] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:15.356035 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 192.168.1.1:60265] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:15.564879 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 192.168.1.1:60265] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:15.785681 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 192.168.1.1:60265] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:15.948873 2014] [:error] [pid 19925] [client 192.168.1.1:60262] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:16.127426 2014] [:error] [pid 20181] [client 192.168.1.1:60265] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:16.360616 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60276] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:16.491222 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60270] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:16.623874 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60270] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:16.770894 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 95.179.9.58:53505] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/build.php?id=24
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:16.778533 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60270] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:16.995152 2014] [:error] [pid 19924] [client 95.179.9.58:53505] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: www.travianx5.ru/build.php?id=24
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:17.075577 2014] [:error] [pid 20206] [client 192.168.1.1:60270] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:17.314743 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60276] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:17.500116 2014] [:error] [pid 20233] [client 192.168.1.1:60271] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:17.670282 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60276] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:17.832341 2014] [:error] [pid 20213] [client 192.168.1.1:60276] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:18.022740 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60282] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:18.227291 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60282] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:18.395933 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60282] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:18.527445 2014] [:error] [pid 20214] [client 192.168.1.1:60282] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:18.656938 2014] [:error] [pid 20229] [client 192.168.1.1:60284] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:18.795898 2014] [:error] [pid 20191] [client 192.168.1.1:60281] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:18.943548 2014] [:error] [pid 20040] [client 192.168.1.1:60292] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:19.413578 2014] [:error] [pid 20229] [client 192.168.1.1:60284] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php
[Sun Jan 26 10:57:19.575589 2014] [:error] [pid 20182] [client 192.168.1.1:60289] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4269, referer: travianx5.ru/login.php

Comment: с подключением к базе данных проблемы

PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Что у вас в файле Automation.php? Только не выкладывайте весь файл...
Только нужную строчку

Comment: >Только не выкладывайте весь файл... Выложите нужную строчку

никто ничего не будет выкладывать - вопрос уже отвечен и принят

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот код сильно завязан на внешних факторах, я не думаю, что посмотрев на него кто-то узнает в чем дело. Используйте отладку с выводом промежуточных значений, что бы локализовать ошибку и понять, что вообще в данный момент происходит.

1. Прежде всего посмотрите в консоль браузера на предмет ошибок JavaScript
2. Что там у Вас - Ajax или редирект? Если Ajax, то посмотрите приходит ли ответ от скрипта и какой, с помощью вывода значений console.log() в консоль браузера.
3. Попытайтесь выдать на свою страницу или в специальный файл для логов всякие промежуточные данные PHP и проанализировать их.

Comment: Добавил логи сервера Apache, это видимо ошибка не JS, а PHP...

Ошибок JavaScript не обнаружено, а вот PHP ошибок вагон и маленькая тележка..