# Как собрать логи php, apache и mysql в ubuntu?

Tags: apache, php, ubuntu, mysql

Добрый день, сервер работает на ОС Ubuntu 13.10. Возникли проблемы с [web-приложением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/291534/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-php-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-javascript), поэтому нужно собрать все логи, которые только можно. Как это сделать? Где их искать?

Comment: Можете Ваш комментарий превратить в ответ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно логи лежат в /var/log

Смотрите `man 5 syslog.conf` или что-то похожее (зависит от того, что за демон syslogd у Вас запущен). У меня в Ubuntu 12.04 -- `man rsyslog.conf`